# Compile all less files into single css file - webpack

Tags: angular, less, webpack

I'm using [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) and I have one folder `assets\less` in which I hold all my `.less` files.

After project is built, I would like to have single `css` file in dist folder.

I found examples how it is done if you use inline styles in component decorator, but I couldn't find what should be the solution for my case.
I guess that I have to specify one more entry point, but that will create `.js` file not `.css`.

Is webpack suited for this anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the extract text webpack plugin then add this to your loaders

```
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css'),
      include: your path
    }
```

And the following in your plugins

```
 plugins: [
  new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[chunkhash].css')
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I'm not sure whether this applies to my situation. I have one `import.less` which contains import files to all other .less files. And I need to compile it to .css file during build process. I don't see how it will be done with this? Am I missing something?

Comment: But that's what the extactTextplugin will do, extract all your css into one file. 
Yes to need to add less loader in your config to compile it.